# Tag users in Facebook post without using drop down

Tags: facebook, facebook-group, facebook-tag

I manage a large Facebook group and once a year we need to delete a big chunk of users. I have already generated a list of these user names and their Facebook IDs, but now I want to copy-paste these IDs into a Facebook post and have the users be automatically be tagged - I don't want to go through the drop down menu that appears when you type `@`. (This way I can say "If your name is on this list, you will be removed" and know that the users will be tagged by facebook and will receive a notification.)

I have tried various things like `@[user-id]` in my post but nothing seems to work. I followed an [old article](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2011/12/02/facebook-photo-tag-trick_n_1126202.html) suggesting something like `@@[user-id:0:text]` would work, but Facebook apparently patched this.

Can anybody help me figure out if it is possible to copy-paste a list of names (or ID's, or a combination with the `@` symbol and any other formatting) and have those names be automatically tagged in the Facebook post? I really want to avoid typing the first few characters, pressing TAB to complete and tag the name, and repeating hundreds of times.

Thanks.

Edit: Tried doing this more recently and the issue still exists. I know you can press ESC to drop out of the name popup but that doesn't work when trying to do this programmatically.

Answer (score -2):

Having problems with tagging a photo when FB offers you a drop-down list of potential names? Here is the solution. Continue writing the name you have in mind. Instead of pressing RETURN right away, press ESC. The drop-down list of suggestions should disappear. Now you can press RETURN.